# _error_handler com o CodeIgniter

Tags: php

No local onde estudo há um sistema de pontos que ocorre um erro quando gero um relatório, não consegui entender a lógica do erro que é o seguinte:

> Um erro do PHP foi encontrado
>      Gravidade: aviso
>      Mensagem: argumento inválido fornecido para foreach ()
>
> Nome do arquivo: content / relatorio.php
>
> Número de linha: 26
>
> Backtrace:
>
> Arquivo: C:\Xampp\htdocs\ponto\aplicativo\views\content\relatorio.php 
>      Linha: 26 
>      Função: _error_handler
>
> Arquivo: C:\Xampp\htdocs\ponto\application\controllers\Ponto.php 
>      Linha: 160 
>      Função: view
>
> Arquivo: C:\Xampp\htdocs\ponto\index.php 
>      Linha: 315 
>      Função: require_once

O _error_handler é

```
foreach ($obrigatorios as $time)
```

E a view

```
$obrigatorios = $this->horario_colaborador->get_horario_colaborador_obrigatorios($colaborador->id, $semestre->id);
```

Não consegui entender quais argumentos estão errados

Comment: Acredito que `$obrigatorios` não está recebendo um `array`. Dá um `print_r($obrigatorios); die;` e posta o resultado.

Comment: @KayoBruno tu de novo? Aff. kkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Com certeza o erro é esse, um `foreach()` deve receber um `array` ou *objeto* como parâmetro. Você pode garantir que o retorno do seu método `get_horario_colaborador_obrigatorios()` seja um **array**  (com valor ou vazio) no próprio método.

Comment: @ErlonCharles égua mah, deixa eu ganhar uns potinhos aqui, tu já tem muito kkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Em qual parte do código eu devo usar o print_r ? Sou bem amador em PHP e creio que realmente não esteja retornando um array, e o print_r não deve funcionar se não for um array (acho que é por isso que não está retornando valores)